# Pygame function to draw a line between two points is not working

Tags: python, pygame

I created a function to try and save the positions of two subsequent mouse clicks and then draw a line between them but it is not working.

This is my code:

```py
import pygame
import pygame_widgets
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((300,300),pygame.RESIZABLE)
points=[]
buttonpress=False
go=True
def drawline():
    pos1get=False
    pos2get=False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        while pos1get==False:
            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                pos1=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                print(pos1)
                pos1get=True
        while pos2get==False:
            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                pos2=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                print(pos2)
                pos2get=True
    if pos1get==True and pos2get==True:
        pygame.draw.aaline(screen,(0,0,0),pos1,pos2)
        print('line drawn')
while go:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            points.append(event.pos)
            
    button=pygame_widgets.Button(screen,0,0,100,50,onClick=lambda:drawline() )
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    button.listen(event)
    button.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Please note: The question [Looping mousebutton down to draw lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477799/looping-mousebutton-down-to-draw-lines) does not answer my question. I want the line to be drawn between two distinct points every time and only after the button has been pressed. If the button has not been pressed, I don't want the program to register any mouse clicks.

The code that I have posted above works but there are 2 issues with it.

1. The line is not visible even thought the pygame function to draw a line is getting executed.
2. Both the points are being registered as the point where I clicked the button.

I have seen and read every Stack Overflow answer I could find related to this question but none of them solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I want the line to be drawn between two distinct points every time and only after the button has been pressed. If the button has not been pressed, i don't want the program to register any mouse clicks.*

Lets code that. First *I want the line to be drawn between two distinct points*. So we need a container to store points. This will be a list that will hold tuples of the beginning and ending position of lines.

Secondly, to answer the *only after the button has been pressed* part. It implies that we need some sort of variable to keep track of if the mouse is pressed. We will call this variable `begin`. Why is it called begin? Because as soon as mouse is pressed, we want to begin to "capture" the mouse position.

```
import pygame
import time

window = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))
points = []
begin = False

while True:
    pygame.event.get()
    window.fill((255, 255, 255))

    if any(pygame.mouse.get_pressed()) and not begin:
        posStart = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        begin = True
```

Now in the same frame, we set `begin` to true. This means that the `posStart` variable holds the position of the mouse in the first frame.

Now, that we have set begin to true, we can start capturing the current position of the mouse.

```
if begin:
        posNow = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        pygame.draw.line(window, (255, 0, 0), (posStart[0], posStart[1]), (posNow[0], posNow[1]))
```

Lastly, we need to set begin to false. And we already know that we need to set begin to false if begin is already true and if mouse is not being pressed. At the same time, we can also add the starting and ending position of the mouse to the points in form of a tuple.

```
if not any(pygame.mouse.get_pressed()) and begin:
        points.append((posStart, posNow))
        begin = False
```

And there you have it. The only thing left to do now is to draw the points.

```
import pygame
import time

window = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))
points = []
begin = False

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            
    window.fill((255, 255, 255))

    if any(pygame.mouse.get_pressed()) and not begin:
        posStart = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        begin = True

    if begin:
        posNow = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        pygame.draw.line(window, (255, 0, 0), (posStart[0], posStart[1]), (posNow[0], posNow[1]))
                                                                                           

    if not any(pygame.mouse.get_pressed()) and begin:
        points.append((posStart, posNow))
        begin = False

    for i in range(len(points)):
        pygame.draw.line(window, (0, 0, 0), (points[i][0][0], points[i][0][1]), (points[i][1][0], points[i][1][1]))
        
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a working version of what I have understood you want:

- After each click you can draw a single line made of two points

I have refactored/changed a bit the code.
If you use MOUSEUP instead of MOUSEDOWN event you will see that every
time you click on the button the first point will be the one inside the
button itself, that is because `allow_draw` will trigger on MOUSEDOWN
and just after the MOUSEUP will be activated.

```py
import pygame
import pygame_widgets
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((300,300),pygame.RESIZABLE)
points=[]
drawing_enabled = False

screen.fill((255,255,255))

button=pygame_widgets.Button(screen,0,0,100,50,onClick=lambda:allow_draw() )
button.draw()

def allow_draw():
    global drawing_enabled
    drawing_enabled = True
    print("Button clicked")

while(1):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and drawing_enabled:
            points.append(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        if len(points) > 1:
            pos1 = points.pop()
            pos2 = points.pop()
            pygame.draw.line(screen,(0,0,0), pos1, pos2)
            print(f'line drawn pos1:{pos1} pos2:{pos2}')
            drawing_enabled = False
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        button.listen(event)
            
    pygame.display.flip()
```